# Constant expressions from an Enum

Tags: java, compile-time-constant

Is there any way of converting an enum into a constant expression?
I want my switch operator to choose among the values of an enum, but I got a compile error "case expressions must be constant expressions", so I tried to declare it in a variable:

```
final int REG = MyEnum.REG.getIndex().intValue();

switch (service.getIndex()) {

case REG:
```

But I still get the same error. According to Oracle's documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value
>   of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is
>   composed using only the following:
>
> •Literals of primitive type and literals of type String

So it isn't working because I'm not using a literal. I think I will have to declare it as:

```
final int REG = 8;
```

But it'd be much better to link it to the enum. Is there any way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Turns out I don't need to use any final variable. It is just as simple as:

```
switch (service) {

case REG:
```

It didn't occur to me till I saw Andrea's comment. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I assume that `service.getIndex()` returns `Integer`, right? Can you modify it so that it returns your enum?

Comment: Till Java 1.6 you can not use `String` in `switch-case`, but you can use it in Java 7. FYI

Answer (score 6):

If possible, modify your `getIndex()` method so that it returns an enum instead of an integer. If this is not possible, you need to **map** the index to an enum element:

Given the following enum:

```
public enum Index {
   ONE,
   TWO,
   THREE
}
```

you can map your index to an enum element by using

```
Index.values()[index]
```

Given your method `Integer getIndex()`,  you can then do something like

```
switch(Index.values()[getIndex()])
    case ONE : ... 
       break;

    case TWO : ...
       break;

    case THREE : ...
       break;
}
```

Note that this might throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to access an index within the enum which is larger than the number of enum elements (e.g. in the sample above, if `getIndex()` returns a value > 2).

---

I would encapsulate the expression `Index.values()[getIndex()]` into an enum method like `valueOf(int index)`, similar to the default `valueOf(String s)`. You can then also handle the valid array index check there (and for example return a special enum value if the index is out of range). Similarly, you can then also convert discrete values which have special meanings:

```
public enum Index {
   ZERO,
   ONE,
   TWO,
   THREE,
   REG,
   INVALID;


   public static Index valueOf(int index) {

       if (index == 8) {
          return REG;
       }

       if (index >= values().length) {
          return INVALID;
       }

       return values()[index];
   }
}
```

This is an example only - in any case, it generally depends on the range of values you get from your `getIndex()` method, and how you want to map them to the enum elements.

You can then use it like

```
switch(Index.valueOf(service.getIndex())) {
   case ZERO : ... break;
   ...
   case REG : ... break;
   ...
}
```

---

See also [Cast Int to enum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878952/cast-int-to-enum-in-java) for some additional information (especially the hint that `values()` is an expensive operation since it needs to return a copy of the array each time it is called).

Answer (score 2):

If you want specific numeral values assigned to enum constacts go like this

```
enum MyReg {
    REG(8), OTHER(13);

    public final int value;
    MyReg(int value) {
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

You then use it like this:

```
class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyReg reg = MyReg.REG;
        switch (reg) {
        case OTHER:
            System.out.println(reg.value);
            break;
        case REG:
            System.out.println(reg.value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```