# Associate enum value to integer

Tags: java, enums

I have this enum:

```
public enum Digits {
    ZERO(0);

private final int number;

    private Digits(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return number;
    }
}
```

And I would like to make setter in another class which can me offer following feature:
- I will give it integer value (in this case, 0) and that setter will set enum ZERO to my local variable of type Digits
Is that possible?
Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast Int to enum in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878952/cast-int-to-enum-in-java)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify please what do you want to achieve?

Comment: One more duplicate candidate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609860/convert-from-enum-ordinal-to-enum-type
Please pay attention that using ordinal or numerical values of `enum` is potentially a bad idea. Why don't you use symbolic names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but not by invoking the `enum`'s constructor, as it's available only within the enum itself.

What you can do is add a `static` method in your `enum` that retrieves the correct instance based on a given value, e.g. `ZERO` if the given value is `0`.

Then you'd invoke that method in your other class when given the `int` argument.

**Self contained example**

```
public class Main {
    static enum Numbers {
        // various instances associated with integers or not
        ZERO(0),ONE(1),FORTY_TWO(42), DEFAULT;
        // int value
        private int value;
        // empty constructor for default value
        Numbers() {}
        // constructor with value
        Numbers(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        // getter for value
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        // utility method to retrieve instance by int value
        public static Numbers forValue(int value) {
            // iterating values
            for (Numbers n: values()) {
                // matches argument
                if (n.getValue() == value) return n;
            }
            // no match, returning DEFAULT
            return DEFAULT;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Numbers.forValue(42));
        System.out.println(Numbers.forValue(10));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
FORTY_TWO
DEFAULT
```

Comment: Can you write it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
private Digits digit;

public void setDigit(int number) {
    for (Digits value : Digits.values()) {
        if(value.getValue() == number) {
            digit = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example how to achieve what you want

```
public enum Digit {

    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3);

    private static final Map<Integer, Digit> mappingMap = new HashMap<Integer, Digit>();

    static {
        for (Digit m : Digit.values()) {
            mappingMap.put(m.getValue(), m);
        }
    }
    private final int digit;

    Digit(int aDigit) {
        digit = aDigit;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return digit;
    }
    public static Digit getByDigit(int aDigit) {
        return mappingMap.get(aDigit);
    }
}
```

This approach has better performance than iterating over all constants for large enums.