# Do-While loop not correctly showing when user gets answer right

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm making a script with a do-while loop that randomly selects a color between 6 colors. Then it asks the person to guess the color.

If they get it wrong it says Incorrect and asks if they want to try again.

If they do it selects a new color (This happens and its ok but i wish it wouldnt but thats not the problem) then they guess again.

The issue occurs when they guess the color right it still outputs saying that they're incorrect. I can't figure out why it happens and need help.

My code is the following:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MCassignment11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rng = new Random();

        String again, guess;

        do {
            int colorchoice = rng.nextInt(5);
            String color;

            if (colorchoice == 0)
                color = "RED";
            else if (colorchoice == 1)
                color = "BLUE";
            else if (colorchoice == 2)
                color = "GREEN";
            else if (colorchoice == 3)
                color = "YELLOW";
            else if (colorchoice == 4)
                color = "ORANGE";
            else
                color = "PINK";

            System.out.println("Guess my favorite color. There are 6 options.");
            guess = keyboard.next();

            if (guess.equals(colorchoice))
                System.out.println("Correct my favorite color is " + color);
            else
                System.out.println("Incorrect. Would you like to try again? (y/n)" + colorchoice);
            again = keyboard.next();
        } while (again.equals("y"));
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing braces {} in last else

Comment: what has this to do with `JavaScript`?

Comment: Can you show an example of an input that you get an incorrect output for? For example, you do realize that this will be case-sensitive as written, right? (I'm just wondering if that's part of the problem).

Comment: One other point: why not use a `switch` for colors? Or, even better, an [Enum type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)? That way, you can just [cast the `int` to `Enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878952/cast-int-to-enum-in-java).

Comment: EJoshuaS you solved my issue, I hadn't realized it was case-sensitive because my teacher said to do that part in all capitals but when I switched it to lowercase it worked. Thanks man

Comment: No problem - you can also try casting the user input to uppercase to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Let me create an answer really quickly to illustrate

Comment: @MacKenzieCutler Strings also have a method called `equalsIgnoreCase` if you want to compare them case-insensitive

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS That works. Thanks for all the help, I think that resolves all my issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue here is that your comparison is case-sensitive, meaning that if the user entered something like `Red`, `red`, or `rEd` or something like that it'll be considered incorrect. (Technically, `Red` and `RED` aren't equal strings).

One option is to use the [toUpperCase() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_touppercase.htm) to make sure that the user input will be treated as if they wrote it with capital letters, like this:

```
if (guess.toUpperCase().equals(color))
```

As @OHGODSPIDERS pointed out in the comments, Java strings also have an [equalsIgnoresCase() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_equalsignorecase.htm) that you could use here too. Either will work.

Also, as @Alessandro pointed out, you should compare `guess` to `color` rather than to `colorchoice`.

One other point:

```
if (guess.equals(colorchoice))
            System.out.println("Correct my favorite color is " + color);
        else
            System.out.println("Incorrect. Would you like to try again? (y/n)" + colorchoice);
        again = keyboard.next();
```

To make sure that you don't prompt the user to keep guessing, you should do the following:

```
if (guess.toUpperCase().equals(color))
{
            System.out.println("Correct my favorite color is " + color);
            // Explicitly set "again" to "n" so that we won't loop again
            again = "n";
}

else
// Add brackets so that it only prompts the user for input if they had a wrong answer
{
            System.out.println("Incorrect. Would you like to try again? (y/n)" + colorchoice);
        again = keyboard.next();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong, `colorchoice` is not a String.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `String` to `int`:

```
if (guess.equals(colorchoice))
```

So you should convert one type to the other before.

You could convert the string using `Integer.parseInt()` or the int concatenating it to `""`.

See following please:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "1";
    int b = 1;
    System.out.println(a.equals(b)); //Prints false
    System.out.println(a.equals("" + b)); //Prints true
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a)==b); //Prints true
}
```